# Do WebDriver findElements retain the Table rows order on its retrieval

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

When retrieving an **html table WebElement list** such as the following (e.g. by tag):

```
webDriver.findElement(By.id("mainTable"))
         .findElements(By.tag("tr"))
```

Is there a guaranteed order for returned list? Can I safely assume element[i] comes before element[i+1] in the table rows order?

I've looked into the [official docs](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html#findElements-org.openqa.selenium.By-), and googled around, but no luck.

Comment: Yes it will come as in the DOM order

Comment: @Madhan - any chance you have a bit more formal reference for that? thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is a guaranteed order for returned list and you can safely assume  element[i] comes before element[i+1] in the table rows order.

You can refer the implementation of findElements() method in [RemoteWebDriver](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/remote/RemoteWebDriver.java) and [By](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/By.java) class with different parameters. What you need is the below code for findElements method, which takes two string as parameters.

```
protected List<WebElement> findElements(String by, String using) {
  if (using == null) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot find elements when the selector is null.");
  }
  Response response = execute(DriverCommand.FIND_ELEMENTS,
      ImmutableMap.of("using", by, "value", using));
  Object value = response.getValue();
  List<WebElement> allElements;
  try {
    allElements = (List<WebElement>) value;
  } catch (ClassCastException ex) {
    throw new WebDriverException("Returned value cannot be converted to List<WebElement>: " + value, ex);
  }
  for (WebElement element : allElements) {
    setFoundBy(this, element, by, using);
  }
return allElements;
}
```

Notice that the method uses [ImmutableMap](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableMap.html) to return the web elements found and add them to a list.

> An immutable, hash-based Map with reliable user-specified iteration
>   order.

Since, ImmutableMap retains the iteration order, you can safely assume the WebElement list return by findElements method is ordered.

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer @Manu. However, I've also looked into the code, and it doesn't seem like ImmutableMap is relevant for the list ordering (as it only contains driver command parameters). There is howevever org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.JsonToWebElementConverter#apply which transforms the raw response into an ArrayList, but it doesn't imply what the original order of the raw response. So unfortunately my question stand still.

Comment: I would suggest you to refer [HttpCommandExecutor](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/remote/HttpCommandExecutor.java), [JsonHttpCommandCodec](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/remote/http/JsonHttpCommandCodec.java), [JsonHttpResponseCodec](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/remote/http/JsonHttpResponseCodec.java) and read about how Http request and Http Response works, then only you can be totally sure of the order.

Comment: Both ImmutableMap map and JsonToWebElementConverter method is relevant for list ordering. [JsonToWebElementConverter](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/remote/internal/JsonToWebElementConverter.java) transforms the response in order and if you want to know if raw response is in order or not, there is no such explicit documentation and you may refer the link I suggested above.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I saw it documented anywhere, but according to my experiences:
- findElement returns first element matching the locator definition (first = as in DOM)
- findElements returns all elements matching the locator definition (order as per DOM)

Comment: thanks, my experiences are similar. However, my concern is that the large scope of driver implementation for the findElements selenium API (e.g. HtmlUnitDriver, chromeDriver, firefox, js, etc.) may result in an inconsistent element retrieval order.