# Get last added element of specific class to DOM via xpath

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

My site generates an arbitrary number of popups (please don't judge my monitization strategy). Each popup is a complex div that I eventually want reference to via xpath, but I specifically want the last one that was added to the DOM, since that will be the one that's on top.

So I tried this

```
//*[@class="popupContent"][last()]
```

I know I could try this

```
(//*[@class="popupContent"])[2]
```

but I have no idea how many of these popups there are.

But in the case of having multiple popups on screen at once, I get a reference to the first one (I'm not sure if this is reliably the case or not). Each of these popups has a popupContainer, but for the sake of this question, it is off limits.

**Given that there are multiple elements with this class, how can I get the one that is on top (and thus interactive)?**

These things aren't siblings, children, or parents of each other. Also, I have no idea how many exist on the page at any given time. I also do not have any control over the content or structure of the popups beyond that I know the class for one of their internal components (popupContent).

**If this is not possible, please explain why.**

I'm looking for a solution that will be compatible in a Java Selenium testing environment. No jquery please.

Comment: Please give a screenshot of case having multiple popups, so that we can know/guess which css attribute(like z-index) control the top popup.  Or you find out that and tell us.

Answer (score 0):

According to this question: [Do WebDriver findElements retain the Table rows order on its retrieval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31230194/do-webdriver-findelements-retain-the-table-rows-order-on-its-retrieval) findElements guarantees order, so in a Selenium environment, I could get the list from that and retrieve the last item.

```
List<WebElement> popups = findElements(By.classname("popup"));
WebElement activePopup = popups.get(popups.size - 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Xpath `(//*[@class="popupContent"])[last()]` and code below should give you same result - last element in the DOM:

```
List<WebElement> popups = driver.findElements(By.className("popup"));
WebElement activePopup = popups.get(popups.size - 1);
```

If last element not the top one try to get focused element:

```
WebElement focused = driver.switchTo().activeElement();
if (focused.getAttribute("class").equals("popupContent"))
    //my active/interactive popup
```

You can check if last one is active now:

```
WebElement lastOne = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//*[@class="popupContent"])[last()]"));
if (lastOne.equals(driver.switchTo().activeElement()))
//last one is active
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach could be to look for the popup with the highest z-index value:

```
private WebElement getTopPopUp() {
    List<WebElement> allPopUps = driver.findElements(By.classname("popup"));
    WebElement topPopUp = allPopUs.get(0);
    for(WebElement popUp : allPopUs) {
        if(Integer.parseInt(popUp.getCssValue("z-index")) > Integer.parseInt(topPopUp.getCssValue("z-index"))) {
            topPopUp = popUp;
        }
    }
    return topPopUp;
}
```

Comment: The popups themselves don't have a z-index in this case, but that would be worth considering if they did.